# Bundle your JavaFX App with a JRE - Mac Edition

Tags: macos, netbeans, javafx, bundle, preloader

I ran into a substantial problem with the way Netbeans packages up Java programs into native Mac Apps (For those who aren't familiar, Netbeans can bundle your Jar file with a JRE so you have a completely self-contained App. Clients don't even have to have Java on their computers to run it. The whole process is explained well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966007/create-a-native-bundle-for-a-javafx-application-that-has-a-preloader/30983359?noredirect=1#comment50004623_30983359)).

The problem I found was that the apps Netbeans produces completely ignore JavaFX Preloaders. I think it's because of the slimmed down JRE that gets added in. I couldn't find any solutions online and wanted to post one here for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Here's what you have to do:

1. Package the app as you would normally, using the process linked above.
2. Right-click the produced app and select **Show Package Contents.** Then enter the **Contents** folder.
3. Enter the **Plugins** folder. This contains the JRE. Delete it.
4. Replace the deleted JRE with the copy stored on your computer. It can be found in *Your Hard Drive* < Library < Java < Java Virtual Machines. Just copy the version you need if there are multiple folders in there.
5. Go back to the **Contents** folder and enter the **MacOS** folder. This contains the shell that runs your Jar file. Open the executable file that's in there with a text editor and delete everything. Replace it with this:

> `#!/bin/sh`
>
> `# Constants
>   APP_JAR="YOURAPP.jar"
>   APP_NAME="YOURAPP"
>   VM_ARGS=""`
>
> `# Set the working directory
>   DIR=$(cd "$(dirname "$0")"; pwd)`
>
> `# Set java location
>   _java="../PlugIns/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java"`
>
> `# Move to correct directory
>   cd $DIR`
>
> `# Run the application
>   exec $_java $VM_ARGS -Dapple.laf.useScreenMenuBar=true -Dcom.apple.macos.use-file-dialog-packages=true -Xdock:name="$APP_NAME" -Xdock:icon="$DIR/../Resources/ICON.icns" -cp ".;$DIR;" -jar "$DIR/../Java/$APP_JAR"`

In the above, substitute *YOURAPP* for the name of your jar file, *jdk1.8.0_05*
for whichever version of Java you added in step 4, and *ICON* for the name of your app's icon, if it has one.

6. If you want to change the app's icon from the standard Java logo, go back to **Contents** and add your own .icns file to the **Resources** folder.

There you have it! The app should run as intended, preloader and all.